# Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7)

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I have this database table:

```
create table users(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    fn varchar(30),
    ln varchar(30),
    sex char,
    email varchar(60),
    country varchar(40),
    username varchar(30),
    password varchar(100),
    primary key(id)
);
```

When I run this code, I am getting an error: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7). I also tried changing `setString(1,fn)` but it's not working.

```
 try{
     String INSERT="INSERT INTO users (fn,ln,,sex,email,country,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
     PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(INSERT);
     System.out.println("Created prepared statement");

     pst.setString(2,"fn");
     pst.setString(3,"ln");
     pst.setString(4,"sex");
     pst.setString(5,"email");
     pst.setString(6,"country");
     pst.setString(7,"username");
     pst.setString(8,"password)");
     pst.executeUpdate();
 }
```

Comment: You are mentioned 7 columns in the query but setting values for 8 columns.

Comment: please post stacktrace!

Answer (score 4):

you have an extra comma in your query and your column count should start from 1.

```
String INSERT="INSERT INTO users (fn,ln,sex,email,country,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
pst.setString(1,"fn");
    pst.setString(2,"ln");
    pst.setString(3,"sex");
    pst.setString(4,"email");
    pst.setString(5,"country");
    pst.setString(6,"username");
    pst.setString(7,"password)");
    pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Try `int i=0; ps.setString(++i, "fn"); ps.setString(++i, "ln");`. That way you don't ever have to worry about the numbers - just maintain the order correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing 8 columns and 7 variables, count doesn't match.

Make sure if this:

```
String INSERT="INSERT INTO users (fn,ln,,sex,email,country,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

should be like this:

```
String INSERT="INSERT INTO users (fn,ln,sex,email,country,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter number relative to the query

```
pst.setString(1,"fn");
pst.setString(2,"ln");
pst.setString(3,"sex");
pst.setString(4,"email");
pst.setString(5,"country");
pst.setString(6,"username");
pst.setString(7,"password)");
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrections:

```
String INSERT="INSERT INTO users (fn,ln,sex,email,country,username,password) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

and

```
short c = 0;
    //using a counter variable (short or int) means
    //no worries about numbering - just maintain the order below
pst.setString(++c,"fn");
pst.setString(++c,"ln");
pst.setString(++c,"sex");
pst.setString(++c,"email");
pst.setString(++c,"country");
pst.setString(++c,"username");
pst.setString(++c,"password)");
```

Note: `++c` is pre-increment operator. It adds 1 to the current value of `c` (sets `c` to this) and uses the new value of `c`.