# Hibernate: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7)

Tags: java, hibernate

Not a duplicate of this question [Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806466/parameter-index-out-of-range-8-number-of-parameters-which-is-7)

My SaltTranDef entity class is

```
@Id
@Column(name="salt_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer saltId;

@Column(name="tran_type")
private String transactionType;

@Column(name="user_id")
private String userId;

@Column(name="parent_system")
private String parentSystem;

@Column(name="parent_sys_ref_id")
private String parentSystemReference;

@Column(name="status")
private int status;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "saltTranDef")
@Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
         org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
private Set<SaltTranUser> saltTranUsers;
```

And the SaltTranUser entity class is

```
@Id
@Column(name="salt_id")
private Integer saltId;

@Id
@Column(name="salt_property")
private String saltProp;

@Column(name="salt_value")
private String saltValue;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="salt_id")
private SaltTranDef saltTranDef;
```

Both the above entity classes extend a mappedSuperclass

```
@Column(name="cre_suid")
private String creatorId;

@Column(name="mod_suid")
private String modifiedId;

@Column(name="cre_date")
private Timestamp creationDate;

@Column(name="mod_date")
private Timestamp modificationDate;
```

When inserting from a JUnit:

```
@Test
public void testInsert(){

    SaltTranDef std = new SaltTranDef();
    SaltTranUser stu1 = new SaltTranUser();
    SaltTranUser stu2 = new SaltTranUser();
    SaltTranUser stu3 = new SaltTranUser();
    Set<SaltTranUser> set1 = new HashSet<SaltTranUser>();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    std.setParentSystem("A");
    std.setParentSystemReference("123");
    std.setStatus(10);
    std.setTransactionType("A");
    std.setUserId("1234");
    std.setCreationDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    std.setCreatorId("1234");

    session.persist(std);
//  session.flush();

    stu1.setCreationDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    stu1.setCreatorId("1234");
    stu1.setSaltProp("Fname");
    stu1.setSaltValue("Swateek");
    stu1.setSaltId(std.getSaltId());

    stu2.setCreationDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    stu2.setCreatorId("1234");
    stu2.setSaltProp("Lname");
    stu2.setSaltValue("Jena");
    stu2.setSaltId(std.getSaltId());

    stu3.setCreationDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
    stu3.setCreatorId("1234");
    stu3.setSaltProp("Phone");
    stu3.setSaltValue("9900056668");
    stu3.setSaltId(std.getSaltId());

    set1.add(stu1);
    set1.add(stu2);
    set1.add(stu3);

    std.setSaltTranUsers(set1);

    session.save(std);
    tx.commit();
}
```

I get an error saying:

> SEVERE: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7).
>   Mar 25, 2015 8:06:35 AM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
>   SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.salt.entity.SaltTranUser]
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7).
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)

Comment: Putting `@Transient` before `@ManyToOne` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

This kind of problem is almost always related to **double column mapping**. And indeed. We can see, that this mapping uses one column twice **`"salt_id"`**:

the `SaltTranUser` entity class:

```
@Id
@Column(name="salt_id")
private Integer saltId;
...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="salt_id")
private SaltTranDef saltTranDef;
```

And that is wrong. Hibernate is at the end inserting into one column twice, i.e. more arguments then columns in INSERT, UPDATE

Solution here would be mostlikely very simple - because the `@ManyToOne` seems to be wrong. I would expect some special column for reference like: **`SaltTranDef_id`**

Comment: This approach I can't work out due to some business reasons.

So, in the second table the Identity column of first table and another column would be a composite primary key. The identity column in the second table would be a foreign key dependent on the first table.

Comment: Mark it as read-only. But in general, my answer is THE answer. Two mappings of one column cannot be used as writeable... Hope it helps

Comment: Now..with some changes in the entity class.. (I have done that read only too) this error isn't coming. But something else is coming up, I am confused if I should edit this question or start a different thread? Help please.

Comment: To get more attention,ask new question. This is down in the stack.

Comment: Here's the new question that I have posted, there are a few changes in the entity classes too. If you could please help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29285225/hibernate-one-to-many-mapping-not-populating-second-table

Answer (score 4):

In my case issue was with `user_type` field. It was defined as discriminator and as public property. It wasn't marked with `@Column` but somehow Hibernate anyway failed on this

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "abstract_users",
    indexes = {@Index(name = "idx__abstract_users__is_enabled", columnList = "is_enabled")}
)
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
// @TODO: rename user_type to discriminator
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "user_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 10)
abstract public class AbstractUser extends CreateUpdateTimestampableBase
{

    // @TODO: rename user_type to discriminator
    public String user_type;

    @Min(0)
    @NotNull
    @Column(precision = 19, scale = 2)
    protected BigDecimal balance;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Hibernate picks up any property that is not marked transient or annotated with @Transient. That is why user_type detected as a database column.

Comment: Can we say that Hibernate does not allow you to use the discriminator column as a property of the class?

Comment: Helped me, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issue when I was using the one-directional mapping (parent class containing child class, but child class doesn't keep the reference of parent class).
The mapping looked like

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name="jobcard_id", nullable=false)
private List<JobServiceMapping> services;
```

I got the error *Parameter index out of range*.
Then I changed the annotations a bit and now it is working for me.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="jobcardId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<JobServiceMapping> services;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your entity, replace

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="salt_id")
private SaltTranDef saltTranDef;
```

by

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="salt_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private SaltTranDef saltTranDef;
```

it worked for me