# JPA composite primary key/foreign key mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 table like

[image]

then i try to mapping with using `@Embeddable` like [This reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177)

**Week_Effort.java**

```
@Entity 
@IdClass(Week_Effort.class)
@Table(name = "week_effort")
public class Week_Effort implements Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2825819221813101109L;

@Id
@Column(name="week_id") 
private int week_id;

@Id
@Column(name="timesheet_id")
private int timesheet_id;

@Column(name="day1")
private int day1;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="timesheet_id" , referencedColumnName =     "timesheet_id",insertable=false, updatable=false , foreignKey =   @ForeignKey(name = "fkweekts"))
private Timesheet timesheet_id ;
.
.
.
//get and set
}
```

**Timesheet.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "timesheet")
public class Timesheet implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7014333990749288304L;

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
@Column(name = "timesheet_id")
private int timesheet_id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="timesheet_id" , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Week_Effort> weekeffort ;
.
.
.
//get and set 

}
```

**WeekEmbed.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class WeekEmbed implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3229945076116848141L;

int timesheet_id;
int week_id;

//get set

}
```

I use AJAX to post parameter as json like

```
{"timesheet_id":1,"day1":"8"} //and more 6 parameter
```

week_id generate by some process and then set it before add with CRUD in Jparepository.But error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (10 > number of parameters, which is 9)
```

How to fix this? What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What is this about? `foreignKey =   @ForeignKey(name = "fkweekts")`

Comment: it's just naming for FK . not  effective to code. @K.Nicholas

Comment: I don't see you need such a thing. You should start with a much simpler setup - no `@JoinColumn` annotation and get that working first. I don't even see where you think you are using your composite key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From :[Hibernate: Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246707/hibernate-parameter-index-out-of-range-8-number-of-parameters-which-is-7)

I change `@IdClass` to WeekEmbed.class and delete some part then add `@Id` to object mapping.

**Week_Effort.java**

```
@Entity 
@IdClass(WeekEmbed.class)
@Table(name = "week_effort")
public class Week_Effort implements Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2825819221813101109L;

@Id
@Column(name="week_id") 
private int week_id;

//Delete this part
//@Id
//@Column(name="timesheet_id")
//private int timesheet_id;

@Column(name="day1")
private int day1;

@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@JoinColumn(name="timesheet_id" , referencedColumnName = "timesheet_id",insertable=false, updatable=false , foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fkweekts"))
private Timesheet timesheet_id ;
.
.
.
//get and set
}
```